# How to add featured image on front end form?

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, front-end, wp-insert-post

I'm working on my first WordPress plug-in for front end posting where signed in users can post and manage their articles on front end.

I'm pretty close to be done but can't find a way to add `Featured Image` on front-end form. I'm not sure if it's possible or not but is there a way to use `Featured Image`(http://grab.by/Lp8e) from back end on front end?

Any resources on this topic will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the relevant code inline. A question should not depend upon code posted to a third party site. (Plus, and no offense intended, I don't have the time to read through your entire plugin to analyze the problem.)

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thank you for the comment! I removed link to my plugin since I just wanted to get generic answer or link to site has some information about it.